# Sandboxed or walled classloader to separate application from runtime environment

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

Web applications for Tomcat are wrapped into a .war file and thrown into Tomcat. The application can use classes inside the war file and contained jar files. This separates the runtime-classes of Tomcat from the application classes.

When using storm (see storm-project.net), there is no similar segregation. Rather the recommended way requires to create a "fat jar", denoting a jar containing all the necessary class files after unwrapping them from their own individual jars. For simple situations this works, but the resulting fat jar must have all the META-INF/* files from all merged jars correctly merged, which does not work semi-automatically.

I would not be shy to write my own class loader which simulates something like a war-file. Except I have no clue how to intercept the default class loader that loads all the classes I deploy.

My theory is that one of the classes of my applications is loaded first by the default class loader. Presumably in its `static`-section I would cast the magic class loader spell such that all dependent classes will then be loaded by my own class loader, which would now how to get the necessary classes from whatever I deem suitable.

Any hints towards the general problems described as well as the specific magic needed are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting the classloader: The default classloader is the one which loaded the class that is currently executing. So if you use a separate classloader to bring in the WAR's entry point, every class reference from it or its (run-time/creation) descendents will default to going through that classloader. That classloader can then decide what it should refer back to a higher-level classloader and what it should reload using its own resolution rules -- the simple rule "only ask the parent for things I don't have available in this plug-in", also known as "parent last", is often sufficient.

Comment: You mean that in my described theory I use the static section of my first class being touched to set up an appropriate class loader and that is it already. Sounds easy enough. There is only one thing I wonder. If after setting up the new class loader the runtime environment (storm) needs more of its own classes: will the default class loader be asked first or mine --- Well, I will go figure, but if you happen to know, I would appreciate the early warning.

Comment: No, I mean that when your server instantiates your first class it explciitly creates the new classloader and uses that to fetch that class. All that class's references will then go to _its_ default classloader, that being the one you created. Classes loaded that way will again see that as their classloader environment, and so on, recursively down the call tree.

Comment: You say (a) "it (the runtime) explicitly creates the new classloader" then you say (b) "All that class's references will then go to its default classloader, that being the one you created.", but I don't see where I should have slipped in my classloader in between?

Comment: Runtime creates the new classloader, and _explicitly uses that classloader to load the plug-in_. The plug-in then considers this new classloader its context, and asks it for any other classes it references.

Comment: "Runtime creates the new classloader" is the problem, because this classloader will not know how to get the classes. I would have to amend or replace it to be able to do the right thing.

Comment: Runtime creates an instance of (let's call it) SandboxClassloader, giving it the classpath or equivalent for the plug-in. That class is part of the runtime's design responsibilities, not the plug-in's. You did say you were willing to write a classloader...

Comment: Ah, uuhhh, grmbl, now I see how I created the confusion. I would not want to touch the classloader of the runtime, but thought to let the plugin have a classloader which takes care of the necessary steps.

Comment: Most of the runtime still uses the Java-provided classloader. You just start up a sandbox classloader for the code you want to run in a sandbox. And unless  your framework defines that, there is effectively no sandbox unless the plugin happens to implement one. Which most won't.